# ImageButton PostBack Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a custom UserControl in Asp.Net. This user control contains an asp:ImageButton wrapped in an UpdatePanel with a ScriptManagerProxy in the UserControl and a parent ScriptManger on the main page that contains the asp:Panel these custom UserControls are added to (renders as a list like object with items). I want to suppress the click from the ImageButton (contained in the UpdatePanel) to NOT fire PostBacks that is causing the page to be refreshed. Here is a snippet of the UpdatePanel wrapped ImageControl within the custom UserControl:

```
        <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"/>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>        
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CatImage" EventName="Click" />    
            </Triggers>    
            <ContentTemplate>        
                <fieldset>              
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="CatImage" runat="server" Height="128px" Width="128px" ImageUrl="../Handlers/ImageResizer.ashx?imgpath=../PhotographicImages/noImageFound.png&amp;w=180&amp;h=180" OnClick="CatImage_Click"/>       
                </fieldset>    
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On the top of the main page that dynamically loads these UserControls to its asp:Panel is:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

This works ONLY for every click AFTER the first click... Meaning the first click causes a PostBack on the main page, but any subsequent click is suppressed.

When this ImageButton is clicked, i fire an event in the CodeBehind to display a "LightBox" object with a larger version of the image.

What is wrong with this code? How can i suppress this first click from causing a PostBack to my parent page?

Comment: Personally i avoid to use updatepanel. Better use ajax through jquery or pagemethods. Your code seems ok to me.

Comment: Mind providing an example link that relates to my question?

Comment: As you use script manager you could use pagemethods. There are plenty of examples on the internet with that. As i told you, your code seems ok to me. So "What is wrong with this code? " is answered and "How can i suppress this first click from causing a PostBack to my parent page? " use pagemethods. :)

Comment: I did look into PageMethods, but was not successful. You can't use PageMethods in UserControls, and i don't really know how to tackle it by dealing with the issue on the main page. Because the underlying issue is in the UserControl...

Comment: Then you can use jquery and ajax. Which you can debug and generally is not "black box" as udpatepanel. check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2008/03/20/ajax-calling-pagemethods-defined-on-a-usercontrol.aspx

Comment: Interesting, i'll try implementing that code.

Comment: As you realize i don't like updatepanel :)

Comment: Try removing the ChildrenAsTriggers part from the updatepanel.. I think that could be the issue? maybe?

Comment: @Humpy, didn't work...

Comment: Strange issue, I copied and pasted your code. I use update panels all the time. Yours worked just fine. Tricky one.

Comment: Currently looking into replacing the ImageButton with the open source LightBox control... looks like this may solve everything... The main purpose of this control is to display a thumbnail. when a user clicks it, display that image in a larger popup window. The lightbox will not send a PostBack.